# slim framework calling functions within functions

Tags: php, function, slim

I don't know if you're supposed to refer to them as "functions" but...

My when my add_record function is called, I want to re-use another function I have made which gets a list of team names from the database;

```
public function add_record($data){

        $teamnames = function get_teamnames;
        print_r($teamnames);
        exit;

        /*

        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO reports(`date`,refereename, refereeteam, hometeam, homecaptain, awayteam) VALUES (

            "'.strtotime($data['date']).'",
            "'.$data['refereename'].'",
            "'.$data['refereeteam'].'",
            "'.$data['hometeam'].'",
            "'.$data['captainname'].'",
            "'.$data['awayteam'].'"
            )');

            */

}
```

And here is my get_teamnames function (from within the same file)

```
public function get_teamnames(){
    //Get team data from database, place into resource.
    $teamsData = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM teamnames ORDER BY teamname ASC');

    // Array which we will return to the Slim router
    $teams = array();

    // PLace all the teams from the mysql resource into the array
    while ($row = $teamsData->fetch_object()) {
      $teams[] = $row;
    }

    // Return the teams array
    return $teams;

}
```

The reason I want the list of teamnames available in my add_record function, is so that I can do some validation on the `$data` and make sure that what's being submitted is only one of those team names stored in the database.

Comment: You can define that function and reuse it indeed, which is good practice. However, I would enforce uniqueness in the database itself, it's what it's good at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these functions are in the same class and you are using an object of the class, just do:

```
$teamnames = $this->get_teamnames();
```